# checkbox is not getting checked in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

```
<tr ng-repeat="languages in samln">
   <td>
      <span>{{languages.emplang}}</span>
   </td>
   <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1-" id="sp1" value="false" style="margin-left:40px;" ng-model="languages.speak">
   </td>
   <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2-" id="rea1" value="false" style="margin-left:40px;" ng-model="languages.read">
   </td>
   <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3-" id= "wr1" value="false" style="margin-left:40px;" ng-model="languages.write">
   </td>
</tr>
```

It has two string values true and false. I gave as value="false" but checkbox is not getting checked and Here languages is a list.

Comment: Here languages is a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
  angular.module('checkboxExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.checkboxModel = {
       value1 : true,
       value2 : 'YES'
     };
    }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>Value1:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value1">
  </label><br/>
  <label>Value2:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value2"
           ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'">
   </label><br/>
  <tt>value1 = {{checkboxModel.value1}}</tt><br/>
  <tt>value2 = {{checkboxModel.value2}}</tt><br/>
 </form>
```

Source: [AngularJS documentation / API Reference / ng / input components in ng / input[checkbox]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="" value="" ng-checked="check" />

in controller 

$scope.check = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

The value attribute isn't really used. Angular uses the model value to set the check.  Sometimes you may need to declare the true / false criteria too.  You can initalize with the ng-init directive like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="sp1" 
     ng-true-value="'true'" ng-false-value="'false'"    
     ng-init="test='true'" ng-model="test">
```

Note that you have to single quote the true / false values since ng expects an expression there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the check-box to be checked by default then use `checked=""` or `checked="checked"`.

Please visit below link for more details.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.checkbox.html

```
   <tr ng-repeat="languages in samln">
       <td>
          <span>{{languages.emplang}}</span>
       </td>
       <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1-" id="sp1" checked="" style="margin-left:40px;" ng-model="languages.speak">
       </td>
       <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2-" id="rea1" checked="" style="margin-left:40px;" ng-model="languages.read">
       </td>
       <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3-" id= "wr1" checked="" style="margin-left:40px;" ng-model="languages.write">
       </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: I am giving the languages.speak, read ,write as strings not boolean

Comment: You have done something wrong otherwise it always works to make check-box checked.